# Kotlin: Разница между apply{} и with()

Tags: kotlin

Может мне кто-то доступно объяснить в чем разница между этими двумя функциями? И в каких кейсах лучше применять ту или иную функцию?

Comment: в документации есть полное описание всех scope функций с примерами https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html

Comment: Я это все видел. Просто не совсем было понятно когда что юзать, потому что они очень похожи. А вот этот нюанс с тем что with возвращает последнее выражение разъяснил разницу

Comment: run тоже возвращает последнее выражение и является по сути "парой" для apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У этих методов есть 2 различия:

- `apply{}` принимает инстанс класса в качестве получателя ( `instance.apply{}` ), в то время как with() требует, чтоб экземпляр был передан в аргументы ( `with(instance){}` ). В обоих случаях `instance` станет `this` внутри блока.
- `apply{}`  возвращает получателя, в то время как `with()` возвращает результат последнего выражения в блоке.

Не думаю, что есть какие-то строгие правила использования этих методов. Обычно `apply{}` используется когда вам нужно что-то сделать с объектом и вернуть его. Когда же вам необходимо выполнить какие-то операции над объектом и вернуть другой результат вы используете `with()`

Comment: А зачем использовать `with` если есть `run`?